# Color blocks of 5 rows using nth-child

Tags: css

I'm trying to use nth-child to color every other group of 5 rows.
The code below works but I don't always know how many total rows there will.
They will always be multiples of 5.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbgcxo2p/

```css
p:nth-child(n+8):nth-child(-n+12),:nth-child(n+18):nth-child(-n+22) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The 1 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 2 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 3 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 4 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 5 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 6 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 7 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 8 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 9 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 10 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 11 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 12 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 13 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 14 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 15 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 16 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 17 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 18 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 19 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 20 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 21 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 22 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 23 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 24 paragraph.</p>
<p>The 25 paragraph.</p>
```

Is there a way to use nth-child to do this for whatever the row count will be?

Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this (better use `nth-of-type`).

```css
p:nth-of-type(10n + 6),
p:nth-of-type(10n + 7),
p:nth-of-type(10n + 8),
p:nth-of-type(10n + 9),
p:nth-of-type(10n + 10) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a heading</h1><p>The 1 paragraph.</p><p>The 2 paragraph.</p><p>The 3 paragraph.</p><p>The 4 paragraph.</p><p>The 5 paragraph.</p><p>The 6 paragraph</p><p>The 7 paragraph.</p><p>The 8 paragraph.</p><p>The 9 paragraph.</p><p>The 10 paragraph.</p><p>The 11 paragraph.</p><p>The 12 paragraph.</p><p>The 13 paragraph.</p><p>The 14 paragraph.</p><p>The 15 paragraph.</p><p>The 16 paragraph.</p><p>The 17 paragraph.</p><p>The 18 paragraph.</p><p>The 19 paragraph.</p><p>The 20 paragraph.</p><p>The 21 paragraph.</p><p>The 22 paragraph.</p><p>The 23 paragraph.</p><p>The 24 paragraph.</p><p>The 25 paragraph.</p>
```