# How to apply the "last child" styling to not the :last-child element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to apply *last child styling* to not the `:last-child` *element*?

Is there a way to specify in html that it is a `:last-child` even if it is not?

Something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li class="last-child"></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Or this:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li last-child></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Same for the `:first-child` and `:selected`.

Comment: Use the order property, flex/grid.

Comment: what is element must be select? if it is'nt last child,why use `:last-child`?

Comment: how can I use flex/grid can you please give me more details?

Comment: use `li:nth-child(number of the child)` if you know how many childs you have.

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195161/how-can-i-select-an-nth-child-without-knowing-the-parent-element?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653526/color-blocks-of-5-rows-using-nth-child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `order` property which comes together with the *Flexbox* / *Grid*:

```css
ul {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks them vertically */
}

ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

ul > li:last-child { /* or "> .last-child" */
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First child</li>
  <li>Second child</li>
  <li class="last-child">Last child but not displayed last!</li>
</ul>
```

By default the value of the `order` *property* is set to `0`, so by giving it the value of `1`, I'm placing it after everyone else; so here I'm only targeting the *"second child"* to make the code as *short/clean/optimal* as possible; I could also target the `:last-child` by giving it the value of `1`, but then I'd also need to target the "*second child*" by giving it the value of `2` to achieve the same result as it is now, but we don't need to use the `order` *property* twice since only once is enough, in this case...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```css
#main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

#main div {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}

/* Safari 6.1+ */
div#myRedDIV   {-webkit-order: 2;}
div#myBlueDIV  {-webkit-order: 4;}
div#myGreenDIV {-webkit-order: 3;}
div#myPinkDIV  {-webkit-order: 1;}

/* Standard syntax */
div#myRedDIV   {order: 2;}
div#myBlueDIV  {order: 4;}
div#myGreenDIV {order: 3;}
div#myPinkDIV  {order: 1;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;" id="myRedDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;" id="myBlueDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;" id="myGreenDIV"></div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;" id="myPinkDIV"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can replace `div#main` with `ul` and child `div` with `li`.